# I got loader error when I was trying to write a set/get function

Tags: vue.js

The error message is:

> You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

I haven't written anything for get/set yet, but I got the error, why?

```
computed: {
  form() {
    set: function() {},
    get: function() {}
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it should be `object` instead of `function` for form

eg.

```
computed: {
  form: {
    set: function() {},
    get: function() {}
  }
}
```